# Identify the fragment a view belongs too

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm using fragments in my app to dynamically add or remove input ui elements in the same way that the contacts app works with phone numbers, email, etc. I can't seem to work out how to remove the fragments however.

The add/remove button for each fragment is part of the fragment itself, and calls the onClick method in the parent activity, which has the button view as the singular argument. I check the background image of the button in order to determine what action to take, add or remove.

Adding works fine, because I simply create a new *MyFragment* object, add it to an array, and display the fragment with fragment manager.

However, for removing, I can't find anything that will let me identify what fragment the calling button belongs to. I need to know what fragment to remove from my array, and be able to target the specific fragment with fragment manager. Is there any way to get the containing fragment of the *view* argument of *onClick*?

Comment: this question need some code for anyone to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [Fragment 1.2.1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.1) or higher, you can use [`FragmentManager.findFragment(vew)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#findFragment(android.view.View)) or the Kotlin extension (in `fragment-ktx`) of [`view.findFragment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#findfragment) to get the containing Fragment.

From there, you can use [`getParentFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getParentFragmentManager()) to get the `FragmentManager` that Fragment is attached to if you don't already have a reference to the correct `FragmentManager`.

Comment: I've been struggling a bit with the android docs, and was so focused on the view that I missed the FragmentManager functions. It of course makes much more sense too. This works beautifully of course, thank you.